# MySQL encoding problems on iOS

Tags: php, mysql, ios, utf-8, encode

So I'm building a PHP site that inserts POST variables into MySQL database. The whole site is encoded in UTF8 to support Hebrew text.

It works excellent on desktop but in iOS the site inserts variables in gibberish for some reason.

this is the PHP code sample:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$fullPhone=$_POST[prefix].''.$_POST[phone];
$sql="INSERT INTO testtab (fbName, fbId, fbComment, name, email, phone)
VALUES('$_POST[fbName]','$_POST[fbID]','$_POST[fbComment]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$fullPhone')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: It might help to give an example or two of how exactly the data is corrupted. Also, "the site inserts variables in gibberish", but where are you seeing that gibberish? In an iOS app? How is the data being displayed on iOS?

Comment: I see the gibberish when I print the table in a PHP file. All hebrew information that came from PC is shown correctly, but information that came from ios is shown as symbols.

Comment: By the way, never just build SQL using these `$_POST` values: Either call `mysqli_real_escape_string` or bind values to `?` placeholders.

Comment: Yeah, well. It's still pretty difficult to work out what the iOS angle might be when you don't give any information about how the data is entered and/or displayed on the iOS device. If that's where the bad data comes from, then some detail on how that data is created and transmitted would seem to be crucial.

Comment: Hey Rob, what does mysqli_real_escape_string prevent? what's the risk of usin $_POST values?

Comment: @user3160630 It prevents [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The risk is that a malevolent user could post a request with a `email` value that could [drop your table](http://xkcd.com/327/) or something nasty like that. More innocently, if the `name` happened to have an apostrophe in it (e.g. `O'Brien`), your code would fail. By escaping it with `mysqli_real_escape_string`, you address both the innocent and malevolent risks that the current code exposes you to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your connection:

```
//if i want to work with hebrew databases
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$connection);//reading hebrew from phpadmin database - only for hebrew sites
```

Like this:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//if i want to work with hebrew databases
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$con);//reading hebrew from phpadmin database - only for hebrew sites

$fullPhone=$_POST[prefix].''.$_POST[phone];
$sql="INSERT INTO testtab (fbName, fbId, fbComment, name, email, phone)
VALUES('$_POST[fbName]','$_POST[fbID]','$_POST[fbComment]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$fullPhone')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: I used $con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); and it fixed the problem. thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue just yesterday with smart quotes and other unicode characters. The solution for me was to make sure that the MySQL connection was set to UTF-8 as well as the tables and HTML. Here is an example:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to the database');

if (!mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn)) {
    echo "Error: Unable to set the character set.\n";
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gather from one of your other comments that you're doing `SET NAMES` to set the character set:

```
$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Obviously, though, you will want to use either `mysqli_real_escape_string` or manually bind the values to the `?` placeholders in your SQL to protect yourself against [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as well as more innocent use of apostrophe in your fields.

But, if you perform the [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) of your parameters, you may therefore need to use [`mysqli_set_charset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) instead of the `SET NAMES` SQL, above:

```
$con->set_charset('utf8');
```

If, on the other hand, you solve the SQL injection problem by using `?` placeholders in your SQL and then use [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to bind the values to those placeholders, then I do not believe it matters if you use `mysqli_set_charset` or the `SET NAMES` SQL syntax.

See the [Character Sets Concepts](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php) discussion for notes on the different behavior between `SET NAMES` and `mysqli_set_charset`.

Comment: a lot of helpful information for me to know. thank you very much!